# Integrating a BU with another CRM org

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

We have a Marketing cloud integration with CRM using Marketing cloud connect.

I have created another business unit in MC and I want to connect this unit with another org in CRM so it will be MCParentBU connecting to CRM1 (already established) and MCChildBU connecting to CRM2 (I am doing this)

We have multi org enabled and I was going to follow the process outlined in the trailhead below to establish the connection.

https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/marketing-cloud-connect/get-started-with-mc-connect?trail_id=use-marketing-cloud-connect

In this trailhead there is a bullet point which concerned me and I was wondering given our setup, is the process to establish a second connection the same as what we did before?
Note: I am going to create a separate api user(s) for CRM and MC.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is correct, if you setup multi-org connector, you will connect to different CRM org separately in SFMC BUs.

1. PROD CRM org connects to PROD SFMC BU, you will need to create API user in PROD CRM, and a API user in SFMC (you should only give this API user access to PROD BU),in SFMC you will **unselect** "Is Sandbox" on Salesforce Integration page.
2. UAT CRM org (sandbox) connects to UAT SFMC BU, you will need to create API user in UAT CRM org, and a API user in SFMC (you should only give this API user access to UAT BU), in SFMC you will select "Is Sandbox" on Salesforce Integration page
3. repeat above process for other environment: SIT, DEV etc

Comment: That is what i did and it has worked as planned. Thank you